# Loop through json (non-object ?)

Tags: php, json, foreach

I want to show a list of TV programs with title, genre, subgenre, description, start time and duration using a json file on server but I  get the following errors:

E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Trying to get property of non-object -- at line 13

E_WARNING : type 2 -- Invalid argument supplied for foreach() -- at line 13

Here is a piece of a sample json:

```
{"channel":"6280",
"banned":true,
"plan":[
{"id":"-1",
"pid":"0",
"starttime":"00:00",
"dur":"65",
"title":"",
"normalizedtitle": "",
"desc":"",
"genre":"",
"subgenre":"",
"prima":false 
},


{"id":"94622386",
"pid":"507461",
"starttime":"01:05",
"dur":"65",
"title":"Sex Researchers",
"normalizedtitle": "sex-researchers",
"desc":"Ep. 2 - Ciclo The Body of...",
"genre":"mondo e tendenze",
"subgenre":"societa",
"prima":false 
},
```

Here is the php code that I use:

```
<?php
$channel = '6280';
$current_unix = time();

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://guidatv.sky.it/app/guidatv/contenuti/data/grid/'.date('y_m_d').'/ch_'.$channel.'.js'));
//print_r($json);

echo '<ul>';

foreach ($json as $data) {

echo '<li>';
foreach ($data->plan as $prog) {

if ( $current_unix < $prog->starttime ) {

echo $prog->id . '<br>';
echo $prog->starttime . '<br>';
echo $prog->dur . '<br>';
echo $prog->desc . '<br>';
if ( isset($prog->genre)) {
echo $prog->genre . '<br>';
}
}
}
echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Could you help me to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: Is that a full JSON sample? because your given JSON is invalid.

Comment: Hi, here you can find the full JSON: http://guidatv.sky.it/app/guidatv/contenuti/data/grid/17_04_22/ch_6280.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot loop on the object. Your JSON does not return the array of channel, but return only a channel object. Here is what you want:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://guidatv.sky.it/app/guidatv/contenuti/data/grid/'.date('y_m_d').'/ch_'.$channel.'.js'));

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($json->plan as $prog) {
    echo "<li>" . $prog->title . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: How can I show the list of tv programs given that JSON?